# What is the difference between the IN operator and = operator in SQL?

Tags: sql, select

I am just learning SQL, and I'm wondering what the difference is between the following lines:

WHERE s.parent IN (SELECT l.parent .....)

versus

WHERE s.parent = (SELECT l.parent .....)

Comment: you should google it before you ask.

Comment: Wouldn't it be awesome if every answer to every tech question was on SO, though? Then when you Googled it, they'd end up here.

Comment: Have you try your query?

Comment: I know, I'll start my own metamoderated knowledge-based community! With blackjack! And hookers! In fact, forget the metamoderated knowledge-based community!

Comment: @user2063626 I answer the question because the user ask and I feel it interesting. I cannot find in `FAQ` that question like this doesn't deserved to have an answer at all. Why don't you downvote my answer? Anyway, i don't care. I've been answering in SO if I feel I can answer the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`IN`

will not generate an error if you have multiple results on the subquery. ***Allows to have more than one value in the result returned by the subquery.***

`=`

will generate an error if you have more than one result on the subquery.

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*IN vs =*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6830b/7)

Comment: Thank You. So, in other words, it is okay to use the IN operator whenever the = operator is used, but not the other way around?

Comment: *..okay to use the IN operator whenever the = operator is used.* -- I didn't get what you mean but the point is, if you the subquery returns multiple values, use `IN`.

Answer (score 4):

when you are using 'IN' it can compare multiple values....like

select * from tablename  where student_name in('mari','sruthi','takudu')

but when you are using '=' you can't compare multiple values

select * from tablenamewhere student_name = 'sruthi'

i hope this is the right answer

Answer (score 4):

The "IN" clause is also much much much much slower. If you have many results in the select portion of

`IN (SELECT l.parent .....)`,

it will be extremely inefficient as it actually generates a separate select sql statement for each and every result within the select statement ... so if you return 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Cow'

it will essentially create a sql statement for each result... if you have 200 results... you get the full sql statement 200 times...takes forever... (This was as of a few years ago... maybe imporved by now... but it was horribly slow on big result sets.)

Much more efficient to do an inner join such as:

```
Select id, parent
from table1 as T
inner join (Select parent from table2) as T2 on T.parent = T2.parent
```

Answer (score 2):

*For future visitors.*

- Basically in case of equals (just remember that here we are talking like `where a.name = b.name`), each cell value from table 1 will be compared one by one to each cell value of all the rows from table 2, if it matches then that row will be selected (here that row will be selected means that row from table 1 and table 2) for the overall result set otherwise will not be selected.
- Now, in case of IN, complete result set on the right side of the IN will be used for comparison, so its like each value from table 1 will be checked on whether this cell value is present in the complete result set of the IN, if it is present then that value will be shown for all the rows of the IN’s result set, so let say IN result set has 20 rows, so that cell value from table 1 will be present in overall result set 20 times (i.e. that particular cell value will have 20 rows).

For more clarity see below screen shot, notice below that how complete result set from the right of the `IN` (and `NOT IN`) is considered in the overall result set; **whole emphasis is on the fact that** in case comparison using `=`, matching row from second table is selected, while in case of `IN` complete result from the second table is selected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`In` can match a value with more than one values, in other words it checks if a value is in the list of values so for e.g.

`x in ('a', 'b', 'x')` will return true result as x is in the the list of values

while `=` expects only one value, its as simple as

x = y returns false

and

x = x returns true

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of thumb is:

The `=` expects a single value to compare with. Like this:

```
WHERE s.parent = 'father_name'
```

`IN` is extremely useful in scenarios where = cannot work i.e. scenarios where you need the comparison with multiple values.

```
WHERE s.parent IN ('father_name', 'mother_name', 'brother_name', 'sister_name')
```

Hope this is useful!!!

Answer (score 0):

**IN**

This helps when a subquery returns more than one result.

**=**

This operator cannot handle more than one result.

Like in this example:

SQL>

```
Select LOC from dept where DEPTNO = (select DEPTNO from emp where
JOB='MANAGER');
```

*Gives ERROR ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row*

Instead use

SQL>

```
Select LOC from dept where DEPTNO in (select DEPTNO from emp
where JOB='MANAGER');
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Sometimes = also used as comparison operator in case of joins which IN doesn't.
2)  You can pass multiple values in the IN block which you can't do with =. For example,

```
    SELECT * FROM [Products] where  ProductID IN((select max(ProductID) from Products),
```

(select min(ProductID) from Products))

would work and provide you expected number of rows.However,

```
    SELECT * FROM [Products] where  ProductID = (select max(ProductID) from Products) 
and ProductID =(select min(ProductID) from Products)
```

will provide you 'no result'. That means, in case subquery supposed to return multiple number of rows , in that case '=' isn't useful.